# Ways of installing APK to device

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I am working on a QOS (Quality Of Service) app for a network service provider. It needs APK to be install on user's phone on the fly. So just exploring my options that is there a way so that application can be pushed on device via network service provider or can be installed from SIM card?

Any quality input would be a great help!